# How to make a low-cost computer desk?

Tags: home

Recently my computer desk was destroyed and I can't use it anymore. As I don't have a lot of money to spend for a new one, is there an alternative way to make a new desk using home appliances or any other things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you need a computer desk, but it sounds to me like you just need a generic desk. If I'm wrong please clarify what additional features you need.

To create a makeshift desk, find a flat surface like a board, cabinet door, standard home door, or something similar. Support it with anything that is about the right height like cinder blocks, old milk crates, or even cardboard boxes.

[image]

Comment: Saw horses can be the supports too.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to basic tools (a saw, hammer, and some nails) you can make a basic desk from discarded wooden pallets (the kind that let a fork lift truck carry a stack of crates).  There are many [instructables](http://www.instructables.com) on making things out of pallet wood, but you probably don't even need to go that far -- just a pallet for the top, with the spaces between boards filled in with more boards, and something (milk crates, for instance) to hold it at a usable height.